# How to save a list of JSON objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I've been searching for a solution, but didn't succeed.

The JSON list of objects I've generated:

```
[
    {
        Email : "e@gmail.com",
        Aanwezigheid : "nodig"
    }, {
        Email : "h@gmail.com",
        Aanwezigheid : "gewenst"
    }, {
        Email : "j@zonnet.nl",
        Aanwezigheid : "info"
    }
]
```

The model:

```
public class Invitee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Presence { get; set; }
};
```

The jQuery ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("NewAppSave","App")',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    accept: 'appication/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    data: jsonData,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            alert("Met succes !");
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

What is the right way to save this data to a SQL Server Database ?
All database fields match exactly with those in the model.

Comment: You need to stringify the data - `data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),` But your model does not contain a property named `Aanwezigheid `

Comment: Modify your js object to include 'Presence' instead of 'Aanwezigheid'. eg. {
        Email : "e@gmail.com",
        Presence: "nodig"
    }

Comment: You would need an `Entity Data model`. Whole json can be serialized and stored as a string in a table column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a same model in c# and then loop through your json model and add to corresponding c# model

Answer (score 0):

your js object

```
var jsonData = [
    {
        Email : "e@gmail.com",
        Presence : "nodig"
    }, {
        Email : "h@gmail.com",
        Presence : "gewenst"
    }, {
        Email : "j@zonnet.nl",
        Presence : "info"
    }
]
```

Your action method:

```
public ActionResult NewAppSave(List<Invitee> invitees)
{
   //use the list data of employees to save this data into db
}
```

in the ajax call, use stringify

```
data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
```